# 1986 Lincoln Town Car will not start from key, but will at solenoid

Tags: ignition, lincoln

1986 Lincoln Town Car will not start from key, but will at solenoid.

have replaced ignition switch, still does this.... turn the key and it will crank, but not fire, but turn key to ON and go under the hood and jump from the S terminal (the one that goes to the start position of the ignition switch) to the + battery cable, and it will crank and fire every time (given enough battery power to crank of course)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this problem is in your question,"I jumped the wire...". This points out a faulty cable. Broken inside of its insulation, or gone dry on one or other of its terminals. If your car turns off OK with the jump wire in place, then simply do the jump wire as a neat re-wiring job and leave that in place instead of the suspect wire. Use the same size wire or slightly thicker to avoid any heat problems. If all is OK with the jump wire in situ then its job done. If the engine will not turn off with the wire substituted you will need a wiring diagram to work out if you are by-passing any switches.